# Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression in my jquery file when I am trying to upload a file

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am getting an Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression in my jquery file when I am trying to upload a file and submit it via ajax. It was working before I added my xhr for the progress bar.

**errors**:

> at.error  @   jquery.min.js:4 bt  @   jquery.min.js:4 At  @   jquery.min.js:4
>   at    @   jquery.min.js:4 x.fn.extend.find    @   jquery.min.js:5
>   x.fn.x.init   @   jquery.min.js:4 x   @   jquery.min.js:4
>   b.show    @   bootstrap.min.js:6 (anonymous function) @   bootstrap.min.js:6
>   x.extend.each @   jquery.min.js:4 x.fn.x.each @   jquery.min.js:4
>   a.fn.tab  @   bootstrap.min.js:6 (anonymous
>   function) @   bootstrap.min.js:6 x.event.dispatch @   jquery.min.js:5
>   v.handle  @   jquery.min.js:5

This is my ajax request along with the progress part:

```
$("#add_certificate_form").on("submit", function() {

    var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);

    $.ajax({
        xhr: function () {
            var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function (evt) {
                if (evt.lengthComputable) {
                    var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total;
                    console.log(percentComplete);
                    $('.progress').css({
                        width: percentComplete * 100 + '%'
                    });
                    if (percentComplete === 1) {
                        $('.progress').addClass('hide');
                    }
                }
            }, false);
            xhr.addEventListener("progress", function (evt) {
                if (evt.lengthComputable) {
                    var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total;
                    console.log(percentComplete);
                    $('.progress').css({
                        width: percentComplete * 100 + '%'
                    });
                }
            }, false);
            return xhr;
        },
        url: '<?php echo Config::get('URL'); ?>certificates/add_certificate_action',
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            if(!data.success){
                $.notify(data.error,{
                    className:'error',
                    clickToHide: true,
                    autoHide: true,
                    globalPosition: 'bottom right'
                });
                //var formData = false;
            }else{
                $.notify(data.success,{
                    className:'success',
                    clickToHide: true,
                    autoHide: true,
                    globalPosition: 'bottom right'
                });
                $.ajax({
                    url:'<?php echo Config::get('URL'); ?>user/edit_profile',
                    type:'GET',
                    headers: {'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'},
                    success: function(data){
                        $('#content').html(data);
                        $("#general").attr("class", "tab-pane");
                        $("#general_tab").attr("class", "");
                        $("#certificate_tab").attr("class", "active");
                        $("#certificates").attr("class", "tab-pane active");
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });

    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
url: '<?php echo Config::get("URL"); ?>certificates/add_certificate_action',
```

Use double quotes in PHP expression